# An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template

Tags: symfony-2.1

I am updating a value using id of a product in symfony2.16 also using MngoDBbundle

but I am getting error like this

> An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("The
>   "acme_store_update" route has some missing mandatory parameters
>   ("id").") in AcmeStoreBundle:Default:index.html.twig at line 1.

this is my controller please check update action

```
<?php

namespace Acme\StoreBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Template;
use Acme\StoreBundle\Document\Product;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;


class DefaultController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("/hello/{name}")
     * @Template()
     */
    public function indexAction($name)
    {
        return array('name' => $name);
    }

// ...

    /**
     * @Route("/create", name="acme_store_create")
     * @Template()
     */
    public function createAction(Request $request)
    {
        $product = new Product();
        //$product->setName('apple');
        //$product->setPrice('19.99');
        $form = $this->createFormBuilder($product)
            ->add('name', 'text')
            ->add('price', 'text')
            ->getForm();
        if ($request->getMethod() == 'POST') {
            $form->bind($request);
            if ($form->isValid()) {
                $req = $request->request->get('form');
                $product->setName($req['name']);
                $product->setPrice($req['price']);
                $dm = $this->get('doctrine.odm.mongodb.document_manager');
                $dm->persist($product);
                $dm->flush();
                return new Response('Name ='.$product->getName().', price ='.$product->getPrice());
            }
         }
            return $this->render('AcmeStoreBundle:Default:index.html.twig', array(
                'form' => $form->createView(),
            ));
    }
    // ...
    /**
     * @Route("/show/{id}", name="acme_store_show")
     * @Template()
     */
    public function showAction($id)
    {
        $product = $this->get('doctrine.odm.mongodb.document_manager')
            ->getRepository('AcmeStoreBundle:Product')
            ->find($id);

        if (!$product) {
            throw $this->createNotFoundException('No product found for id '.$id);
        }
        return new Response('Name ='.$product->getName().', price ='.$product->getPrice());
        // do something, like pass the $product object into a template
    }
    // ...
    /**
     * @Route("/update/{id}", name="acme_store_update")
     * @Template()
     */
    public function updateAction(Request $request,$id)
    {
        $dm = $this->get('doctrine.odm.mongodb.document_manager');
        $product = $dm->getRepository('AcmeStoreBundle:Product')->find($id);
        $form = $this->createFormBuilder($product)
            ->add('name', 'text')
            ->add('price', 'text')
            ->getForm();
        if ($request->getMethod() == 'POST') {
            $form->bind($request);
            if ($form->isValid()) {
                $req = $request->request->get('form');
                $product->setName($req['name']);
                $product->setPrice($req['price']);
                $dm->flush();
                return new Response('Name ='.$product->getName().', price ='.$product->getPrice());
            }
        }
            return $this->render('AcmeStoreBundle:Default:index.html.twig', array(
                'form' => $form->createView(),
            ));

    }
            // ...

}
```

my index.html.twig is

```
<form action="{{ path('acme_store_update') }}" method="post" {{ form_enctype(form) }}>
    {{ form_widget(form) }}

    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

How to update the value using id please help me

Answer (score 5, accepted):

in updateAction add `$id` to your template vars:

```
return $this->render('AcmeStoreBundle:Default:index.html.twig', array(
    'form' => $form->createView(),
    'product_id' => $id,
));
```

and in your template add the `product_id` param to the `path` function:

```
<form action="{{ path('acme_store_update', {id: product_id}) }}" method="post" {{ form_enctype(form) }}>
    ....
```

http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/routing.html

Answer (score 3):

In my case, the error was not in the template file in the error output but in a TWIG file it was extending. In the twig file I was using:

```
path( app.request.attributes.get('_route'))
```

..to try to get the URL path. This created an error because a required parameter was not supplied.

I used the correct way to get the URL:

```
{{ path(app.request.attributes.get('_route'), app.request.attributes.get('_route_params')) }}
```

..and the error went away.

Comment: This fixed it for me too! Was making a call to path(app.request.attributes.get('_route')) somewhere in a layout while visiting a /blog/{id} style route.

Answer (score 0):

In Its routing file mistakenly typed Id instead of token so this error happening 
(An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("The `acme_store_update` route has some missing mandatory parameters (`id`).") in AcmeStoreBundle:Default:index.html.twig at line 1.)

for eg:in .yml file 
ibw_job_edit:

```
pattern:  /{id}/edit
defaults: { _controller: "IbwJobeetBundle:Job:edit" }
```

instead of this u have to write 
ibw_job_edit:

```
   pattern:  /{token}/edit
    defaults: { _controller: "IbwJobeetBundle:Job:edit" }
```